# How can I refactor an angular app that has a global css rule to change base font-size?

Tags: css, angular, sass

My team has recently taken ownership of a large monorepo angular 9 app. While refactoring it, we've discovered that the following global rule exists:

```css
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

This was added over 3 years ago by developers who are no longer with the company. Because it's at the root level, each subsequent component has larger than normal `rem` based font sizes to counter this behavior.

Considering that there are over 200 scss files with almost 4,000 rules using `rem` units, how do I approach removing this root level rule?

Additionally, apart from these `rem` unit based rules, what other css rules would have to be updated?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here by removing the root size declaration?

Comment: We're extracting components into an external library and publishing it on a private artifact feed. The idea is to use these common components in other products down the line. However, our standardization effort has hit a roadblock because standard font sizes are being affected by this base size.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have hit a roadblock rather you have come across a large piece of work related to the standardisation effort. Your code depends on a global value and you wish to modify that value so it is expected that some considerable changes will fall out from that. It seems like you just need to go through each relevant `rem` declaration and modify the value by the calculated difference, e.g. 13px = 62.5% + 1.3rem becomes 13px = 100% + 0.8125rem.